# token is not being generated after upgrading to firebase messaging 17.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I noticed the in `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0` `FirebaseInstanceIdService` has been deprecated so tried overriding `onNewToken()` in `FirebaseMessagingService` but it seems like it never gets called.

and `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken()` return an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete`
```

is there anything in particular that I'm missing?

So I have followed the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) and here is my code

**Manifest:**

```
<!--<service android:name=".network.AppFirebaseInstanceIdService">-->
    <!--<intent-filter>-->
    <!--<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />-->
    <!--</intent-filter>-->
    <!--</service>-->
    <service
        android:name=".network.AppFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**AppFirebaseMessagingService:**

```
 @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Refreshed token: " + s);
        sendRegistrationToServer(s);
    }
```

**In Activity:**

```
    _btnTemptest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

      FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true);

      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      // which throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete` 

     }
    });
```

Comment: onNewToken should get called.  I don't have a problem with this in my apps.  You might want to dig in a bit more into that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there anything in particular that I'm missing?

No you are not missing anything

> **Suggestion**

**Don't Use** `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken()` sometime it throw an exception( i have also face the same issue)

> how to get Token

You need to Use

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, newToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
 });
```

For more information check it here [firebase github link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/e2405c806715a30ea385a4b7aa18bf45e95b7c4c/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MainActivity.java#L99)

Comment: thanks your solution works for manual request. I still wonder why the onNewToken(String token) is not being called ?

Comment: @Poorya check this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/e2405c806715a30ea385a4b7aa18bf45e95b7c4c/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MainActivity.java#L99

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() is returning null for me, and I've spent over a day trying to work out why.

Comment: @DaveNottage have you tried `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()..addOnSuccessListener()`

Comment: @NileshRathod Attempting to call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId() for me causes an exception because FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() returns null.

Comment: @DaveNottage strange can you share that crash log?